# Using Sudo commands via Webpage

Tags: command-line, permissions, apache2, python, security

I am working on the webpage where you click the button run the file in superuser.
I am trying to run mininet topology using the python script via web page.

```
<?php
$mininet='sudo python loadbalancing.py';
$python=exec($mininet);
echo $python;
?>
```

When I excecute the above code, it doesnt' return anything.

However when I execute below code, it return *** Mininet must run as root.

```
   <?php
    $mininet='sudo python loadbalancing.py';
    $python=exec($mininet);
    echo $python;
    ?>
```

Can someone help me, how to run the mininet python script via web page.

I have set the super permission via "visudo" and chmod, but still doesn't work.
In the visudo, I have added the following.

```
%sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/loadbalancing.py
```

I have set

```
sudo chmod 777 loadbalancing.py
sudo chmod 755 loadbalancing.py
```

But still doesn't work or execute the python script in the web page.

Note: Dont concern about security as there will be authentication process before this process.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any difference in the code blocks except for indentation. And you haven't said what you did with visudo or chmod.

Comment: @muru, I have updated the question. Would like to know the possible way to execute sudo command via webpage, the will be authentication before this process.

Comment: What you could try is to make a bash script with just `sudo python loadbalancing.py` command. Add to Sudoers `username ALL = NOPASSWD: /path/to/bashscript` Then change the .php variable to `sudo /path/to/bashscript`

Comment: @user633551 So close, but still didn't work it didn't response/didn't return anything.thx

Comment: Have you tried running the bashscript from the terminal with `sudo /path/to/bashscript` command? If so, what does it say?

Comment: @user633551 i can run the bash file without sudo and it run the python file with sudo. However, it doesn't run when I execute in web page.

Comment: Hmm, you should log the sudo command. In the php variable put in this `sudo /path/to/bashscript > /path/to/log.txt`. Then paste the result from the log file.

Comment: @user633551, thanks-- it created log.txt however nothing in there!

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a few assumptions here...  I suspect your second code paste was meant to be identical to your first - just without the sudo.  Which is why you got the "must be run as root" error.  I also suspect your first code block didn't return anything because it got stuck at an interactive sudo password prompt.

I don't know anything about php or mininet, but when I see your snippet above, I wonder if the user account running the script has the ability to sudo without password.  For example, if your script was running as "myuser", then you would need something like this in the /etc/sudoers file:

```
myuser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Without "NOPASSWD", your service gets stuck waiting for myuser's password at a sudo attempt.  Since the service can't handle an interactive prompt, it dies and you get nothing returned.

standard warning:  sudo without need for password is dangerous.  Using it to run arbitrary commands based on user input from a web page is crazy bad unless you are in a contained sandbox environment.

Comment: after your edits, I see you have "NOPASSWD" for the sudo group.  Is the account that runs your webserver in the sudo group?  Can you su to that user and cleanly run the sudo command without error?  Maybe try to have the script execute "sudo pwd" and trap that it's in the correct directory, or try getting to run a simple "hello world" python script before trying to run loadbalancing.py...

Comment: I have tried "python hello.py" and it does run well. But the mininet (loadbalancing.py) doesn't run, even with "sudo pwd" doesnt return anything. thx

Comment: any output in /var/log/syslog?  or in the web server's log?  I wonder if there is an AppArmor or SELinux issue...I'm just a hack with that stuff, but sudo'ing inside a service might be blocked by some kernel security module that prevents such things.    If your script doesn't need to run perfectly on-demand, maybe it can run in the cron every X minutes and drop its output to text.  Then your webpage can just read in and display the text.   Or your web page could write a marker file and the cron job could watch for the marker file and then execute the python script.

Comment: I am trying to run mininet python script which required power user "sudo".